# Data Insertion Synchronization issue in two mysql tables

Tags: php, mysql, asynchronous, uploadify

I have two tables

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `property` (
`id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `name` longtext NOT NULL
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
 ) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=545 ;
```

Other table is

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `property_images` (
`id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`property_id` bigint(44) NOT NULL,
`image` varchar(555) NOT NULL
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=3071 ;
```

In my website,users have to save/upload new property.they type property details and Upload images via uploadify.After this they click save button to save property details.
While they upload images via uploadify,On server side,I get max id of property and add 1 to it(increment it) and save images for that propertyid.

Simple is images saved before property details.

Issue is when one user uploads images,meanwhile if other user save his property,these images assigned to it,so most of the time different images assigned to different properties.

What can i do here so that i avoid this issue?

Comment: Your structure doesn't seem to be correct. What reason do you have to devide this property enity over two tables? Why don't you add column image to table property?

Comment: Bcoz you do not know how many images a user will upload?you can not do in that way...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `MAX(id) + 1` you should use [`LAST_INSERT_ID()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) function.

```sql
INSERT INTO property (name) VALUES ('Property1');

INSERT INTO property_images(property_id, image) VALUES 
(LAST_INSERT_ID(), '/path/to/your/image1.png'),
(LAST_INSERT_ID(), '/path/to/your/image2.png'),
(LAST_INSERT_ID(), '/path/to/your/image3.png');
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/89d4b/1)** demo

Comment: It is clearly mentioned in question that Property images saved before property details...while a user is uploading images,meanwhile it is saved to images table..after this he saves property details

Comment: Regardless how clear it has been mentioned if you want deterministic behavior it's **the only way** (meaning one way or another but you have to have a row in properties before you insert images) given your schema. As a solution you can insert a property with a default or empty name value in order to generate an id before you save images. And after all images are saved update this particular column.